# Junction ~~ Junction behavior

Tags: raku

I want to check if all elements of an Array have given type.

```
$ raku -e 'my @t = 1,2,3; say all(@t) ~~ Int'
True

$ raku -e 'my @t = 1,2,3,"a"; say all(@t) ~~ Int'
False
```

Works as expected so far. Now I want to allow two types:

```
$ raku -e 'my @t = 1,2,3,"a"; say all(@t) ~~ Int|Str'
False
```

Why is so? If `1 ~~ Int|Str` is `True` for single element why does it fail for `all()` elements junction?

BTW: This question is about understanding `Junction ~~ Junction` behavior (which is also a bit undocumented), not about alternative way of performing check from example (which I know is possible).

Comment: I recommend everyone wanting to understand `Junction ~~ ...`, both how it works in current Rakudo, and ways it may (hopefully will imo) evolve in the future, reads [this thread](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2021/05/msg9960.html), or at least Larry Wall's comments in it, starting with "In general, the left side of `~~` should not be auto-threading...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few additional lines may help clarify what's going on:

```
say all(1,    2,   3)  ~~ Int|Str; # OUTPUT: «True»
say all('a', 'b', 'c') ~~ Int|Str; # OUTPUT: «True»
say all(1,    2,  'c') ~~ Int|Str; # OUTPUT: «False»
```

That is, `all(1, 2, 'c') ~~ Int|Str` is asking "is it the case that all of `1, 2, 'c'` are `Int`s or, alternatively, is it the case that all of `1, 2, 'c'` are `Str`s?"  Since neither of those is the case, it returns `False`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is counterintuitive to natural language semantics:  `all(@items) ~~ any(Type1, Type2)` reads literally as "all items are of any mentioned type" while "all items are exactly one of mentioned type" should be `all(@items) ~~ one(Type1, Type2)` instead.

Comment: BTW: I've found elegant solution that avoids grep: `all( @t ) ~~ subset :: where Int|Str;`.

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr I didn't provide an alternative, since you said you weren't interested in one, but I personally prefer `all @t.map(* ~~ Int|Str)` to the `subset` approach.  But both work.

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr I recommend you read [this thread](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2021/05/msg9960.html), or at least Larry Wall's comments in it, which include "In general, the left side of `~~` should not be auto-threading...".